# Basic program in spring boot

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, error-handling

there is an error in the main class of spring boot application.The error is given below.my program will not work.please help me to solve this.

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The type org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
- The method run(Object, String...) from the type SpringApplication refers to the missing type 
ConfigurableApplicationContext
```

POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.letsstartcoding</groupId>
    <artifactId>springbootexample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <!--       **<version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version> // update this to latest**
         <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### employee.java

```
package com.springboot;

import java.util.Date;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

/*import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;
*/
@Entity
@Table(name="Employees")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
private Long id;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @NotBlank
private String name;
    @NotBlank

private String designation;

    @NotBlank
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
private Date createdAt;
    @NotBlank
    private String expertise;
public String getExpertise() {
    return expertise;
}

public void setExpertise(String expertise) {
    this.expertise = expertise;
}
}
```

### Employeedao.java

**this is the dao class i included the code for insert delete and update**
    package com.dao;

```
import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import com.springboot.Employee;
@Service
public class EmployeeDAO {
    @Autowired
    static

    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    /*save employee*/
    public static Employee save(Employee emp) {

        return employeeRepository.save(emp);

    }

    /*search an employee*/
    public List<Employee> findAll(){
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }



    /*get an employee by Id*/

    public Employee findOne(Long empid) {
        return employeeRepository.findOne(empid);/*getOne*/
    }
    /* delete an employee*/

    public void delete(Employee emp) {
         employeeRepository.delete(emp);
    }


    /*update an employee*/


}
```

## controller class.....with comments i have explained the details.

i have to test it using postman.#

```
     package com.Controller;

    import java.util.List;
    import javax.validation.Valid;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

    import com.dao.EmployeeDAO;
    import com.springboot.Employee;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/company")
    public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
        EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
    /* save an employee*/
    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee emp) {
        return employeeDAO.save(emp);}


    /*get all employees*/

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
        return employeeDAO.findAll();
    }
    /*get employee by empid*/

    @GetMapping("/employees/(id)")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable(value="id") Long empid){
    Employee emp = employeeDAO.findOne(empid);  
        if(emp==null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(emp);
    }

    /*update an employee*/

    @PutMapping("/employees/(id)")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@PathVariable(value="id") Long empid, @Valid @RequestBody Employee empDetails ){
        Employee emp = employeeDAO.findOne(empid);  
        if(emp==null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        emp.setName(empDetails.getName());
        emp.setDesignation(empDetails.getDesignation());
        emp.setExpertise(empDetails.getExpertise());
        EmployeeDAO ed = new EmployeeDAO();

    Employee updateEmployee = ed.save(emp);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(updateEmployee);
    }
    /*delete an employee*/

    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable(value="id") Long empid ){
        Employee emp = employeeDAO.findOne(empid);  
        if(emp==null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    employeeDAO.delete(emp);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }}

##main application class ##
** Spring Boot,Restful API,JPA, Hibernate, MySQL CRUD.basic program**



 package com.restapi;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableJpaAuditing

    public class EmployeeApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run( EmployeeApplication.class, args);
    }
    }
```

#### aplication.properties.file

```
Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

### Hibernate Properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: What are the two backticks doing? `</dependencies> here`

Comment: sorry ignore that black ticks thats my mistake in uploading code in stack overflow

Comment: is it possible for you to paste your code here to understand more. it will help others to understand what exactly you have done..

Comment: sir the edited code is not working.actually that errors was made when i write it in stack overflow

Comment: @gheeshma : refer    https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ link

Comment: I am more curious to understand how you created the project. Did you use https://start.spring.io/ to create your project or you simply created a Maven Archetype-Web project and converting it to Spring boot. By looking at the code I haven't seen the class which has main method and marked with @SpringBootApplication.

Comment: by maven archetype